# Putting a 2nd order ODE into matrix form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been given the following equation, to convert into two first order ODEs:

$$ml \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} = -mg \sin\theta -\beta \frac{d\theta}{dt}$$

I then rearranged:

$$\frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} = \frac{g\sin\theta}{l}-\frac{\beta}{ml}\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$

After that I did:

$$x_1= \theta~~~\text{and}~~~x_2=\theta'$$

Which gives:

$$x_1'=x_2~~~\text{and}~~~x_2' = \frac{g\sin(x_1)}{l} -\frac{\beta}{ml} x_2$$

Then to convert into matrix form I did:

$$\pmatrix{x_1'\\x_2'} = 
\pmatrix{0 & 1\\ \frac{g\sin x_1}{l}&-\frac{\beta}{ml}}
\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2}
$$

However, I realise that I can't take the $x_1$ out of $\sin(x_1)$, only to be replaced by $1$. Any help on how to deal with the $x_1$ in the sin-function, would be much appreciated.

Comment: OMG please clean up your notation in the first half of the problem. You know how to use MathJax; use it please.

Comment: Are you allowed to linearize $\sin\theta$?

Comment: The equation is not linear so it's not possible to write it on the form $X' = AX$ with the matrix $A$ independent of $X$. What you have done looks fine.

Comment: If you really want to write it in the form $X'=A(X) X$ then you'll need to divide $\sin(x_1)$ by $x_1$. (You also lost a minus sign.)